# Passing Shell Context Variables to Compiled Language (Java/C/C++) in Posix

Tags: java, c++, c, shell, ipc

This is a pretty simple question, but I haven't been able to find an answer to it.

I am running a shell script, and within the scope of that shell script I have defined some variables. I want to somehow access those variables from within a program run from within the shell script's context. For example, if I run a script that looks like

```
#!/bin/sh

VARIABLE_NAME="somevalue";
java Main;
./compiled-c-or-cpp.out
```

how might I access `"$VARIABLE_NAME"` from within Main or the compiled C/C++? Honestly I wouldn't be surprised if it's impossible but I figure this is a question worth asking.

***I don't think I can use environment variables for this.*** I am aware of how to access environment variables through Java's `System.getEnv("VARIABLE_NAME")` method and C's `getenv("VARIABLE_NAME")` method. However the procedure I end up implementing will be used in a *very* multithreaded application. I need to be able to use ***context*** variables so that I can have multiple threads accessing their own `"$VARIABLE_NAME"` simultaneously, instead of `export`-ing environment variables to the whole shell.

That said, I admittedly don't have a complete understanding of the scope of environment variables. For example if each call to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./script.sh")` (for Java) or `system("./script.sh")` (for C/C++) is assigned its own shell, and if I am able to `export` environment variables to only that temporary shell, then that would be a tolerable solution.

Thanks to anyone for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export an environment variable to just one process, without having it in your shell:

```
VARIABLE_NAME="somevalue" java Main
```

In your case, it would more likely be like this

```
VARIABLE_NAME="somevalue" (java Main; ./compiled-c-or-cpp.out)
```

Comment: Ok I just want to let you know this worked (!) but StackOverflow won't let me accept your answer within such a short time of asking the question. Thank you so much, both for the answer and for answering so quickly. You will receive a green check in a few minutes.